# Java programming Beginner While-Loop

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I’m writing a while-Loop program for a set of animals which is unkown to me. the user can enter how many they want but terminate it when "exterminate" is entered.

Here is what i need to do for the program:
Write a program that uses a while loop to repeatedly ask for the user to
name an animal and then asks how many are left in the wild. It should stop when the special code EXTERMINATE is entered, and name the animal that is least endangered.

Name an animal? Komodo Dragon
How many are left in the wild? 5000
Name an animal? Manatee
How many are left in the wild? 8000
Name an animal? Kakapo
How many are left in the wild? 91
Name an animal? Florida Panther
How many are left in the wild? 100
Name an animal? EXTERMINATE

The least endangered animal is the Manatee.
There are still 8000 left in the wild.

I have two problems. First, i cannot get the program to store all the animal names to get the elast endangered one outputted. So i was thinking if i should be using arrays to keep track of them?

Second, when i enter exterminate, the program finishes the while loop without breaking after the user inserts exterminate in.

Please don't make it complex because im new to java and don't know multi-dimensional arrays or do-while loops etc.

Here is what i wrote so far;

```
    public static void animals()
{

    String animalname = "";
    String animalsleft = "";
    int noanimals = 0;

    while(!animalname.equals("exterminate"))
    {

        animalname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal"); 
        animalsleft = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many are left in the wild");
        noanimals = Integer.parseInt(animalsleft);
        System.out.println(animalname + " " + animalsleft);

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The least endangered animal is the " + animalname + ".");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + animalsleft + " left in the wild."); 

}
```

Comment: Probably editing your title and your question trying to make it short explaining *exactly* where are you stuck, removing "I'm a begginer", etc might bring better answers (or some) and prevent downvotes. And also posting a [Runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be good

Comment: `"So i was thinking if i should be using arrays to keep track of them?"` - Sounds reasonable.  Did you try that?  `"the program finishes the while loop without breaking"` - Should it break?  There's a `break;` statement to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the String values each time you loop through.

What you want to do is use a List of strings.

eg.

```
 ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();

 while(!animalname.equals("exterminate"))
 {

     animalname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal"); 
     animals.add(animalname);
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array you must first have the number of repetitions through the loop that you will take. For instance, if you are going to run through the loop 100 times, initialize your array to

```
String[] animalNames = new String[100];
```

Then in your while loop

```
int i = 0;
while(i < animalNames.length) {
     animalNames[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal"); 
     i = i + 1;
}
```

This way your array will still have all of the animal names.

Comment: I realize that, but since he is a beginner I'm assuming he just learned about arrays in school. He probably hasn't gotten to lists.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is a simple one. And there are multiple approaches to solving the problem.
But firstly you need to reexamine your question (how it is asked).

But you will learn that in time. For now the solution: obviously u could use arrays, but a better way to do that is using lists. But all that is unnecessary you can easily avoid using all that memory. Simply use a temporary buffer and check each time whether the new animal is endangered. Just add the following lines in the code.

```
public static void animals() { 
    String animalname = ""; 
    String animalsleft = ""; 
    int noanimals = 0;
    String prevanimalname = ""; 
    String prevanimalsleft = ""; 
    int prevnoanimals = 0;
    while(!animalname.equals("exterminate")) {
        animalname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal");
        animalsleft = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many are left in the wild"); 
        noanimals = Integer.parseInt(animalsleft); System.out.println(animalname + " " + animalsleft);
       if (noanimals > prevnoanimals) {
            swap(prevnoanimals, noanimals);
            swap(prevanimalname, animalname);
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The least endangered animal is the " +  prevanimalname + ".");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + prevanimalsleft + " left in the wild.");
}
```

You can google swapping two variables, and apply the same swapping for name ofbthe animal in the same if statement.

And mostAnimalCount holds the count of animal with most numbers. At the end u can simply show dialog box with these numbers and names.

Comment: You are overcomplicating the solution

Comment: @redFIVE the solution I provided is the simplest one. Bear in mind programming is not just about achieving a desires task, its about acheiving while using least possible resources.

Comment: Are you seriously trying to give me a programming lecture?

Comment: @redFIVE in response to your earlier complaint, I have updated the code. It wasn't run on an IDE so there might be some errors in there. But all you need to do is right there. And in response to your second one when you join a community and ask for help on your assignments that is what you usually get with lectures wherever you've made a mistake.

Comment: Uh, I wasn't the one asking the question, reading comprehension is sparse these days I suppose...